# Section heading sytle

Tags: writing-style

I am writing my thesis right now and I vaguely remember that I was once told that in an English paper/manuscript nearly all words of a section title start with an uppercase letter.
For instance:

The Influence of the 19th Century on some Important Stuff

(just something I came up with)
Is this right? Currently I am doing it a little bit inconsequently which is in my opinion even worse. Is there a certain style recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a pretty good summary at: [Scribbr](https://www.scribbr.com/academic-writing/capitalization-titles-headings/)

But note that some universities will have a required "style guide" as do many journals. Your advisor can probably point you in the right direction, as could any of the office staff in the department.

But doing it inconsistently is a problem. Stop doing that.

Comment: I've attended four different schools during my 2 undergrad degrees ( I was pretty nomadic in my twenties) and my go-to method was either reference the school's writing guides that were usually laid out in the course documents, or default to the Chicago Manual of Style for everything. Kind of like the United States 10th Amendment, anything not explicitly federal, defaults to the states.